# Chunks not saving self-closing tags. Any way to fix?

Tags: modx, modx-evolution, modx-chunks

I've set up a brand new site on 2.6.5.

As per my usual practice, I set up a head chunk. However I noticed it was not saving. On experimentation I see that it is not saving self-closing tags.

For example

```
<head>
  <title>My test page</title>
</head>
```

Saves fine.

```
<head>
  <base href="[[++site_url]]">
  <title>My test page</title>
</head>
```

Will not save.

There are no errors. I have manually cleared the cache.

I have also tried:

```
  <base href="[[++site_url]]" />
```

and I have tried using both a mark up plugin (Ace) and without.

Would anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is because of mod_security. Kindly check with hosting support.

Another resource to consult, it is for MODX Revolution but server side situation would be similar and gives you clues: https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/getting-started/installation/basic-installation/installation-on-a-server-running-modsecurity